# Convert variables in bulk from character to date in a specified format

Tags: date, variables, format, character

I am trying to convert character variables into date variables all at once. The character variables are formatted in this way

```
"dd/mm/yyyy"
```

The function that I have used is:

```
datenames <- c('regis_date_temp')
REGCON_CA_FIRM[datenames] <- lapply(REGCON_CA_FIRM[datenames], as.Date)
```

However, the result is a date variable with the following format:

```
"00yy/mm/dd"
```

I have tried to pass more arguments to the function as.Date, but it didn't work.

In the end, of course, the idea is to include more variables in 'datenames' so I can do it all at once, but in the meantime, I would appreciate it if somebody knows how to get around this issue.

Please, let me know with your comments.

KR
Ruben